# Продолжить счет времени после изменения объекта Calendar (Java)

Tags: java

Имеется созданный объект `Calendar`:

```
Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
```

Получаем текущее время и выводим его:

```
System.out.printf("\n%1$s %2$td %2$tB %2$tY года - %2$tH:%2$tM:%2$tS\n", "Дата:", с);
```

Вывод консоли:

```
Дата: 18 декабря 2019 года - 22:12:37
```

Теперь меняем кол-во часов на 6 утра:

```
с.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 6);
```

Получаем:

```
Дата: 18 декабря 2019 года - 06:12:37
```

**И тут вопрос:** как организовать алгоритм таким образом, **чтобы продолжился счет времени дальше**, но уже с учетом измененных количеств часов?

**Предположение:**

Создавать в потоке постоянно объект типа Calendar - не вариант, время будет всегда устанавливаться в текущее (будет сбиваться установленное количество часов, в данном случае 6 утра). Или получать значение времени в миллисекундах, присваивать это значение переменной `time` и уже (далее работать с этой переменной) в блоке `try` с задержкой в секунду с помощью метода `sleep(1000)` постоянно прибавлять по 1000 миллисекунд в переменную `time`? Может есть что-нибудь более оригинальное?

Comment: Ну сделайте статичекский метод, который бы возвращал вам время. И часы, которые меняются, тоже статикой. А в самом методе инициализируете новый Calendar и устанавливаете в него часы. Цель вообще какая? Иметь возможность получить с любого места измененное время? Менять(устанавливать часы) тоже можно с любого?

Comment: Смысл создавать статический метод и постоянно интциализировать Calendar? Время будет постоянно текущее. Задача - запустить часы с измененными часами, минутами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю забыть про Calendar и воспользоваться api, доступным начиная с java 8:

```
import java.time.Clock;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    //создаём фейковые часы, в которых время всегда будет на 10 минут опережать системное
    Clock fakeClock=Clock.offset(Clock.system(ZoneId.systemDefault()), Duration.ofMinutes(10));
    //выводит на консоль текущее системное время
    System.out.println(Instant.now());
    //выводит на консоль время на 10 мин позже системного
    System.out.println(fakeClock.instant());

    //отдыхаем 5 секунд
    Thread.sleep(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5));

    //выводит на консоль текущее системное время (предыдущее значение +5 сек)
    System.out.println(Instant.now());
    //выводит на консоль время, на 10 мин позже системного (предыдущее значение +5 сек)
    System.out.println(fakeClock.instant());
  }
}
```

То есть часы будут идти с установленным нами отклонением от системных. Можно их один раз создать, сохранить в каком-нибудь филде и обращаться к ним по мере надобности за "искривлённым" временем.

Правда, возникает вопрос - а зачем это вообще нужно? Если цель - отображать время в разных часовых поясах, то нужно воспользоваться стандартным апи для установки таймзоны